# Can't get list of all Dataset with INFORMATION_SCHEMA and SCHEMATA on BigQuery project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, information-schema

I'm trying to get all dataset from a project in BigQuery.
So I use this query

> SELECT * FROM project_id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;

But I only get 1 dataset instead to have 30.
I have checked and I think I have all the necessary permissions, being `Owner` for the IAM

On the cloud shell terminal, I get all dataset without problem with this following command

> bq ls --format=prettyjson --project_id <PROJECT_ID>

Any help at all would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` must include a *region qualifier* as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets-schemata#scope_and_syntax).

If you do not specify any region, (just like your provided query), **US would be the region of scope by default**.

For you to retrieve other **datasets** you own, you may use below query in which you must specify a **REGION** and then retrieve them per region.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your-project.`region-REGION`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

You may refer to this [BigQuery SCHEMATA view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets-schemata) documentation for more information.

Comment: I think, last time (just few days ago) I read this documentation it said if no region specified - it returns for ALL regions! Now it makes sense! even though - having 'ALL' would be mucho preferable

Comment: Thank you Scott B and Mikhail Berlyant for your answers, I agree that having the "ALL" is more preferable